# list all the variables in a Bash script with a certain pattern

Tags: bash

I want to list all the variables in a Bash script with a certain pattern.

For example:

```
repo_website_branch
repo_website_gitUrl
repo_playground_branch
repo_playground_gitUrl
```

When I try:

```
echo "${!repo_@}"
```

I get the following output in the console:

```
repo_website_branch repo_website_gitUrl repo_playground_branch repo_playground_gitUrl
```

But when I try:

```
echo "${!repo_*_gitUrl@}"
```

Expected result:

```
repo_website_gitUrl repo_playground_gitUrl
```

Current result:
Nothing is output in the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `*` doesn't act as a special pattern character in this kind of parameter expansion. You may try

```
for v in "${!repo_@}"; do [[ $v = *_gitUrl ]] && echo "$v"; done
```

or

```
compgen -v -X '!repo_*_gitUrl'
```

instead.